# Colour points for x-axis plot R

Tags: r, plot, colors

I want to give the points relating to the first 130 x-axis values a different colour than the rest (up to 250). So basically, divide the points vertically with two different colours. Is this possible and how would you go about it?

Comment: Given the accepted answer, your condition should _really_ have been: the first 130 __rows of the data frame__. Also, "divide the points vertically" remains a mystery to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using base R you can try

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col = rep(1:2, times = c(130, nrow(iris)-130)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

I would use `ggplot2`

Here are some examples:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg,color = mpg < 20)) + 
  geom_point()


ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg,color = mpg < 20)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg,color = mpg < 20)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(color = 'mpg less than 20')

ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg,color = mpg < 20)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values =  c('purple4','springgreen4'))
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row_number for the colours.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data(mpg)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(colour=row_number(displ)<=130) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=displ, y=cty, col=colour)) +
    geom_point(show.legend=FALSE) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

And seems there is a tie at about 3.5.